# Does the Corsair Force GS have built-in Trim support at hardware level?

Tags: macos, ssd

I'm thinking about putting this SSD into my Macbook Pro and I was wondering if Trim support is at the hardware level because afaik OS X doesn't support OS level trim?

[http://www.amazon.com/Corsair-Force-Series-2-5-Inch-CSSD-F180GBGS-BK/dp/B008FYEVU8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008FYEVU8)

Thanks.

Comment: The operating system has to support Trim in order to issue the command.  Try working on your accept right.

Comment: Why the heck would this be voted down? It's a legitimate question.

Comment: He's asking if the device Trims w/o the OS issuing the command.

Answer (score 1):

From a description of the device:

> TRIM Support
>
> Force Series 3 SSDs feature support for the Windows® 7 TRIM command.
>   This allows them to store only the data they need and perform memory
>   optimization to ensure the fastest possible write speeds.

So no, it's not built in, the OS still has to issue the command.

That said, this [software](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/37852/trim-enabler/) appears to do it for you.  It's 64bit enabled.  There has been success running it on SNL to ML.  You have to be using a Core2Duo or later.

Answer (score 1):

TRIM is a file system / hard disk driver feature. The OS uses it to tell the SSD it can wipe a sector, but does not need to do it immediately. In this way the SSD can manage the zero-ing internally and increase performance (and reduce ware) by combing wiping operations (and hopefully perform them at a time when the disk is not busy). In addition it can use the space to do more ware-leveling.

If the OS does not support the command, all the SSD can do it to carry out the zeroing operations faithfully as there's not enough information for it to determine the OS'es true intention.

However, there're tools to enable TRIM for non-apple SSDs on OSX 10.6+.

Comment: Do you know of these tools?

Comment: @DanielFischer - I linked you to one.

Comment: Everett. Thanks. From my research it seems that Trim support isn't absolutely needed. Hardware level GC can be enough.